# Assigning a variable as a key in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key

I'm attempting to use a variable that points a character in a string argument to update it as the program proceeds. However, I'm getting a key error 4. I thought I could use the variable as a key for a dictionary?

````
    result = {}
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i] in result:
            result[text[i]] += 1
        else:
            result[text[i]] = 1
    most = text[0]

    for item in result:
        if result[item] > result[most]:
            most = result[item]
        else:
            if result[item] == result[most]:
                came_first = min(text.index(item), text.index(most[0]))
                most = text[came_first]
    return most


if __name__ == '__main__':
    maximumOccurringCharacter('maximumOccurringCharacter')```


```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/blith/PycharmProjects/test/main.py", line 21, in <module>
    maximumOccurringCharacter('maximumOccurringCharacter')
  File "/home/blith/PycharmProjects/test/main.py", line 11, in maximumOccurringCharacter
    if result[item] > result[most]:
KeyError: 4
````

Comment: Key Error means the key is not in your dictionary. Try troubleshooting by printing the dictionary. Perhaps your key is a string '4' instead of an integer.

Comment: Ahhh yes, thank you, I'm selecting the key's value, instead of the key itself and assigning it to most.

Answer (score 0):

I was assigning the key's value to most instead of the key which changed the downstream comparison since the conditional could not find a key that was now an integer. Thank you @Thatcher Thornberry.

Answer (score 0):

You can accept this answer to mark it as completed.

Key Error means the key is not in your dictionary. Try troubleshooting by printing the dictionary. Perhaps your key is a string '4' instead of an integer.